# Asterisk SendURL() using grandstream UCM6204

Tags: asterisk

We need to invoke URL contains the caller number each time there is an inbound call, we are using Grandstream UCM6204 PBX.

There is a function called SendURL() that can be used through Asterisk, I connected to Asterisk using PuTTy but I'm not sure what to do next?

After doing some research, I found that I couldn't have direct access to Asterisk through UCM devices, which will not allow us to modify the dial plan.

Is the only approach by creating a third party application to communicate with AMI and do the job? Problem with this scenario that this application should be online and working 24/7.

I wrote C# code to accomplish this, but it is not working as expected.

```
    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        AstCon = new ManagerConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["astHost"],
                int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["astPort"]),
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["astUser"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["astPass"]);

        AstCon.NewState += astCon_NewState;
        AstCon.ConnectionState += astCon_ConnectionState;

        try
        { 
        AstCon.Login();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(
                $"Error connecting to {ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["astHost"]}. Error: {ex.Message}");

            // Terminate Application
            Application.Exit();
        }

    }


    private void astCon_NewState(object sender, NewStateEvent e)
    {


        if (e.ChannelStateDesc.ToLower() == "ring" && e.Connectedlinenum == "6401")
        {


                if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ScreenPopPath"] != null)
                {
                    var runString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ScreenPopPath"];
                    runString = runString.Replace("{callerid-number}", e.CallerId);


                    Process.Start(runString);
                }


            }

    }

    void astCon_ConnectionState(object sender, ConnectionStateEvent e)
    {
        connectionStateLbl.Text = AstCon.IsConnected() ? $"Connected to: {AstCon.Username}@{AstCon.Hostname}" : $"Disconnected, reconnecting to {AstCon.Hostname}...";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CURL function. But for invoke it need understand PBX dialplan and hooks

You can use external AMI app.

You can read CEL events in database.

Comment: Thank you, I approached that by programming external app that connects to the PBX and does the logic once a new call is coming